# PHP Date strtotime() Conversion error

Tags: php, strtotime

I am trying to parse a date. I have a `XPathDom` parsed, and I got a date from it. eg. "`1 Nisan 2018 Pazar 15:00`". This equals "`1 April 2018 Sunday 15:00`".

If I try:

```
strtotime("1 April 2018 Sunday 15:00")
```

It return time.
But when I try send a variable like this:

```
strtotime($value[0]->nodeValue)
```

It returns false everytime.

I searched this on Google and Stackoverflow, cannot find a solution.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What does `var_dump($value[0]->nodeValue);` show? It's almost certainly not a valid date.

Comment: If you receive the date like that `1 Nisan 2018 Pazar 15:00`, it's normal than it make an error. `strtotime` can only recognised words from this list : http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: var_dump($value[0]->nodeValue); returns string.

Comment: @Eiji I used str_replace() for it and translated Sunday = Pazar, Nisan = April. It work when I manually strtotime("1 April 2018 Sunday 15:00"). It gives error when I try to use in array loops (while, foreach etc.)

Comment: what kind of string? Can you show the results of the var_dump?

Comment: @Eiji `string(27) "24 Eylül 2017 Pazar 15:00"`

Comment: Well, your replace is not working ^^

Comment: Can you add the part of the code where you're doing the replace?

Comment: After Xpath! I have a function that replaces Turkish day & month names to English ones. @JohnConde asked `What does var_dump($value[0]->nodeValue); show?` and I sended var_dump of `$value[0]->nodeValue`

Comment: Well, I think he want you to `var_dump` the data that you are currently sending to the strtotime. Can you add your code to your initial post? It's kind of hard to "guess" what is wrong in your code without any line of it...

Comment: @Eiji I tried every single line code but did not worked. I looked var_dumps before, after, while changing. It return string. In strtotime returns false.

Comment: Can't help you without any code...

Comment: @Eiji https://eval.in/980369 this is my last trials. If you want I can submit other Turkish strtotime function.

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump(deneme($date[$i]));` instead of `var_dump(strtotime(deneme($date[$i])));` in the while and show it.

Comment: @Eiji I already tried. Returns string. There is no problem with function and $date[$i]

Answer (score 0):

I have do a try on local

```
    $arr = ["1 Nisan 2018 Pazar 15:00","1 Nisan 2018 Pazar 15:00","1 Nisan 2018 Pazar 15:00","24 Eylül 2017 Pazar 15:00","24 Eylül 2017 Pazar 15:00"];
    $RowCount = count($arr);

    // Fikstür Sonucu
    $i = 0;
    $result = array();
    while ($i < $RowCount) {
        var_dump(strtotime(deneme($arr[$i])));
        echo deneme($arr[$i]) . "<br>";
        $result[] = [
            "date" => $arr[$i]
        ];
        $i++;
    }
```

It work perfectly...

```
C:\wamp\www\test\debug.php:48:int 1522540800
2018-04-01 
C:\wamp\www\test\debug.php:48:int 1522540800
2018-04-01 
C:\wamp\www\test\debug.php:48:int 1522540800
2018-04-01 
C:\wamp\www\test\debug.php:48:int 1506211200
2017-09-24 
C:\wamp\www\test\debug.php:48:int 1506211200
2017-09-24
```

Comment: Did you tried it with XPath? It is working when I create  array. I am trying to use this in queries